# Getting "json parser error" after sending form data to the server

Tags: php, ajax, json

```
function ajax()
{
$('form').submit(function() {

  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
  $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()));

  return false;
  });

}
```

After this form I'm getting the json data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "firstName",
        "value": "fsdfdf"
    },
    {
        "name": "lastName",
        "value": "df"
    },
    {
        "name": "emailAddress",
        "value": "refdfdfd.56@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "password",
        "value": "fdfdddd"
    },
    {
        "name": "phoneNumber",
        "value": "fdfdf"
    }
]
```

I'm sending it to the server by this response.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

$json = "http://ec2-54-201-121-123.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/refer247/registration";
$jsonfile = file_get_contents($json);
var_dump($jsonfile);
echo json_encode($_POST);
 var_dump(json_decode($jsonfile));  
 echo json_decode($jsonfile);
?>
```

But after this I am getting json parser error. What actually is happening? I don't know. When I include datatype as text then my success function is calling but I want to send to the server only json data. What I'm doing wrong here...?

I appreciate if i get some help. Thanks.

Comment: IS there a json response in http://ec2-54-201-121-123.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/refer247/registration?

Comment: What, precisely, is giving you a JSON parser error? (I can't even tell if you mean the PHP, or the JavaScript). What, exactly, does that error say?

Comment: in javascript from ajax call its giving the error...

Comment: @cubuzoa...yes that is the service url where i need to send my json data..